# Spring Boot Security + Keycloak adapter 401 Response when token expires while antMatchers is permitAll()

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

When i login i receive access_token and refresh_token which i send in every HTTP request as headers to the Spring boot server.

Problem that i have is when token expires i get 401 Response when i try to access routes that are accessible without authentication, so result is i can't access /v1/users/current which checks if token is valid if not take refresh token and give me a new access token.

What Im trying to do now is make /v1/users/current accessible without any type of authorization/authentication so i can receive a new access token, and I'm not sure how to achieve that using KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

I've tryed to use HandlerInterceptor but preHandle request that i receive is already been trough keycloak and i recieve simmilar error like 401.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: When i use POSTMAN and send a get request to /v1/users/current without access token(No auth) and with refresh token in header i still get access to /v1/users/current route and get the new access token i need.

```
    @KeycloakConfiguration
class ResourceServerConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        //the below three lines will add the relevant CORS response headers
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/v1/users/current").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/register/admin").hasRole("admin")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/*")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }

/*    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/v1/users/current");
    }*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter is checking each http request that has Authorization HTTP header, which means if you need to access a route without checking it you send it without Authorization headers.

I've changed my /v1/users/current to POST without header and I'm sending access_token and refresh_token in request body.